# Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Tags: json, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an error "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'". I am trying to add data as a Codable struct to submit to firebase. However this error keeps popping up. Here is my code (in swift).

```
    do {
        try db.collection("users").document("i").setData(user)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Here is the struct:

```
public struct User: Codable {
    var id: String
    var first_name: String
    var last_name: String
    var email: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case first_name
        case last_name
        case email
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I am misunderstanding Codable but I am following tutorials exactly. I tried replacing user with ["user": user] nut that just crashes the app. Please help! I am following the firebase website example https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: I think that you should add the data as setData(from:  user) instead of setData(user). Can you share with us a more complete example where we can see how you are structuring this user?